# How do I get, build and be able to run the latest on the Magenta repo?

Tags: magenta

I've followed the documented Magenta setup approach based on the bash script as described here https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/README.md on my Ubuntu 14.04-based machine and that works fine.  However, I'd like to get and use some of the latest scripts and models on Magenta which the standard installation process doesn't seem to bring with it.

How do I get, build and be able to run the latest on the Magenta repo?  Note that I'm mostly interested in the contents here: https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models.  In case it helps narrow down the question further, then let's say how can I set up just the scripts and related build process pertaining to this folder: https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/multi_event_rnn.

Thank you